# Slow work with collection. MongoDb+C# (Official C# driver for MongoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a collection with 1.5 million elements. 
I have created indexes on this collection.

This is how I get collection:

```
var query = new BsonDocument();
var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("EndDate");
mongoCollection = (IOrderedFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>)_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName").Find(query).Sort(sort).Limit(21);
var x = mongoCollection.ToList();
```

But when I use LINQ to work with collection it works slow. Nearly 4s

```
    foreach (var item in x.Skip(1))
                {           
                    Model model = new Model();
                    model.GUID = item.GUID;
                    model.ServerIp = item.ServerIP; 
                    result.Add(model);;
}
```

Why so slow?

Comment: Why are you converting `mongoCollection` to a `List`? There is no need for that as you are iterating over it in the `foreach`  loop, however, with 1.5 million records it will consume a lot of memory.

Comment: But collection won't  work in loop without converting.
And I think MongoDB should work faster

Comment: Jaco, he has limit 21 and it is normal to do ToList()

Answer (score 0):

LINQ queries are *always* translated to aggregation framework pipelines